# Are there any hooks for user modification events in google apps?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-email-settings-api

Currently the bane of my existence is dealing with users email signatures at work, changing names, titles, departments, new users...it's all annoying. Currently I manage it with [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/) and a semi templated HTML file to push changes, which works okay, but it's still a manual process. What I'm looking to do is create a small app script or app engine project that can...

1. detect a new or changed user
2. pull the fields needed to fill in their signature template
3. push the changes to their account

2 & 3 are no problem at all, it's #1 that I cannot find a reasonable solution to.

I had thought about using the [google apps audit settings](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6000244?hl=en) to email a specific mailbox when a new user is created, but that will only catch new users, not changes in titles and such. My only apparent option is something that runs periodically checking all the users signatures against what my script would generate and updating if needed, but that's hardly efficient and creates a potential timelapse in the waiting period meaning when people want things 'done now' (which is of course, every request), it will mean I manually trigger the job; effectively bringing me back to my original solution.

Is there any kind of user feed that contains changes available in google apps? Maybe google has a POST hook that hits a predefined URL on changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use push notifications for this https://developers.google.com/drive/web/push  using the users.watch method  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/watch